# Passing values between forms in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP and MySQL search where a user select a area and matching result are shown. Then when user click on any one result I needed to pass the unique id or name to next form. The search part work but I was confused on passing the name or id to next form since there will be multiple results. There is just one form for all the result and it fetches data from DB based on id or name.

Comment: the id is the one that should be unique in a table, so send that!

Comment: But the problem is  how to pass that value to next form.(its just like a shoping site where you search and select a item. When you select it takes you to a page which gives you a detail info about that item)

Comment: add a `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id ?>'>`. But without any code from your side it's impossible to guess the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables from a form is most simply done with either the "POST" or "GET" method in your form to the next page.

Form Methods - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Example from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

```
  <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
     Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
     Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
     <input type = "submit" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables using HTTP method `GET` or `POST` is a good way.

Using method `GET` will make your variables appear in your url like:

`www.example.com?id=1&name=William`

You can do something like this:

```
<form action="your/uri/here" method="GET">
Id:<input name="id" value="<?php echo empty($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:'';?>">
Name:<input name="name" value="<?php echo empty($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:'';?>">
<button type="submit">search now</button>
</form>
```

In your PHP code you should judge whether the `id` or `name` is empty, then, just fetch the result from database according to the search variables.